# Format C++ code with corresponding elements over multiple lines

Tags: c++, vim, ide, indentation, code-formatting

I'm looking for a tool that makes out of the ugly block

```
if   ( str == "str" ) decorator["str"] = &Props::goodstr;
  else if ( str == "strM" )
      decorator["strM"] =     &Props::goodstrM;
  else if ( str == "strXL" )     decorator["strXL"] =     &Props::goodstrXL;
  else if ( str == "strXXXL" ) decorator["strXXXL"] = &Props::goodstrXXXL;
```

the nice block that is easily editable over multiple lines in the visual-block mode in vim:

```
if      ( str == "str"     ) decorator["str"    ] = &Props::goodstr    ;
else if ( str == "strM"    ) decorator["strM"   ] = &Props::goodstrM   ;
else if ( str == "strXL"   ) decorator["strXL"  ] = &Props::goodstrXL  ;
else if ( str == "strXXXL" ) decorator["strXXXL"] = &Props::goodstrXXXL;
```

Or something very similar.
It doesn't have to be in vim! I just tagged it vim, because that's what I normally use. Please recommend other tools that can do this job.

Comment: I don't think there are enough formatting options in vim to be able to do that without manually editing all the lines and inserting the necessary whitespaces. Hopefully an uber vim expert will prove me wrong :)

Comment: It doesn't have to be in vim! I just tagged it vim, because that's what I normally use. Please recommend other tools that can do this job.

Comment: You should add that to your post.

Comment: Do you want a tool that make it at once or help you to do it ?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to have a tool that does it automatically. If that doesn't exist, I'd fall back to a tool that helps me do it

Comment: Use a pretty printer such as GNU `indent`, or [uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know actually a tool that could help on aligning all that "ugly" block. It is called [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294). All you have to do is give him the pattern that you would like to align.

So for the above code you can do that:

```
:%normal! ggJ
:%s/;/;\r/g
:%left
:AlignCtrl =Clp1P1IW 
:% Align (\|)\|]\|[\|&.\+ 
:% Align ;
```

As you can see from the 5th command you need manually reorganise the code by providing the pattern

Result:

```
if      ( str == "str"     ) decorator [ "str"     ] = &Props::goodstr     ;   
else if ( str == "strM"    ) decorator [ "strM"    ] = &Props::goodstrM    ;   
else if ( str == "strXL"   ) decorator [ "strXL"   ] = &Props::goodstrXL   ;   
else if ( str == "strXXXL" ) decorator [ "strXXXL" ] = &Props::goodstrXXXL ;
```